# Numpy one hot encoder is only displaying huge arrays with zeros

Tags: python, numpy

I have a `(400, 1)` numpy array that has values such `4300, 4450, 4650...` where these values can be distributed around 20 classes i.e. `4300 class 1, 4450 class 2...` and tried the below code to transform that array to one hot encoded list. The `y_train_onehot` is showing a list of 400 arrays where each array has a size > 4000 i.e. each array has around 4000 zeros. How can I fix that in order to have one hot encoded vectors for each value i.e. `4300` can be `00001`.

```
def convertOneHot(data):
    y=np.array([int(i[0]) for i in data])
    y_onehot=[0]*len(y)
    for i,j in enumerate(y):
        y_onehot[i]=[0]*(y.max() + 1)
        y_onehot[i][j]=1
    return (y,y_onehot)

y_train,y_train_onehot = convertOneHot(data)
```

[image: sample from y_train_onehot]

Comment: Could you add a minimal representative sample and explain the expected result?

Comment: @Divakar i just uploaded a screenshot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some not optimized example:

```
def convert_to_one_hot(y):
  levels=np.unique(y)
  n_classes=levels.shape[0]
  one_hot=np.zeros((y.shape[0],n_classes),"uint8")
  for i in xrange(y.shape[0]):
    for index,level in enumerate(levels):
      if  y[i]==level:
        one_hot[i,index]=1
  return one_hot
```

**EDIT 1** One less readable but more elegant version:

```
def convert_to_one_hot2(y):
  levels=np.unique(y)
  one_hot=(y==levels).astype("uint8")
  return one_hot
```

Answer (score 0):

I used Pandas Dummies and it's very simple.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> s = pd.Series(y_train)
```

And then

```
y_train_onehot = pd.get_dummies(s)
```

[image: hot_encode]